# Visual Studio - Setup or Change Build Process

Tags: visual-studio, ant, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to add a folder with files inside my application during the build phase of my application in VS 2013. I am creating for a Windows 8, and Windows 8 phone app.

In Android, our company uses an ant file to carry out this task, that swaps in the correct folder with files during the build process.

Does anyone know how to configure the build process in the project settings? And what type of file would be used in replace of an ant file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio uses MSBuild file to allow programmable changes in build phase. Add the MSBuild file to the project as follows:

1) Create xml file into project

2) Also link files to project in advance:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="www\**">
      <DeploymentContent>true</DeploymentContent>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

3) Reference xml file through *.vcxproj file in order for it to built for the project using msbuild.

a) Right-click project -> Unload b) Right-Click project again -> Edit *.*proj file
c) Reference the msbuild file inside the project anywhere within the project tag, something like:

```
  <Import Project="js.build" />
```

4) Right-click project -> Reload

5) Change xml project file (in my case js.build) to copy files from one location to another
   ex (in my case):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MySourceFiles Include="..\..\..\www\**"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyFiles">
    <Message Text="CopyFiles Target" Importance="high"></Message>
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"
        DestinationFiles="@(MySourceFiles->'www\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
        />

  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
       <CallTarget Targets="CopyFiles"></CallTarget>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: thx man, u saved me a lot of trouble with that, have an upvote :)